# Highcharts position tooltip at the middle of stacked bar

Tags: javascript, highcharts, tooltip, stacked

I've been trying to use the tooltip positioner to get the tooltip at the middle of each stacked bar instead of the right side but I've not been able to find any variable that could be use to calculate the x of the appropiate point.

```
    tooltip: {
        positioner: function (labelWidth, labelHeight,point) {
            return {
                x: point.plotX - this.chart.hoverPoint.pointWidth,
                y: point.plotY + this.chart.plotTop - labelHeight
            };
        }
     }
```

Here is a codepen that show how it fails on the last point:
http://jsfiddle.net/vw7ebd4k/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate the tooltip position you can use `point.h` and `labelWidth`. Try something like that:

```
tooltip: {
    positioner: function (labelWidth, labelHeight, point) {
        return {
            x: point.plotX - point.h/2 + labelWidth/2,
            y: point.plotY
        };
    }
 }
```

To remove the unnecessary line between tooltip and point you can use `tooltip.shape` property.

```
shape: 'rect'
```